# Optimize VLOOKUP for large datasets

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to compare two worksheets WS1 and Ws2. The code reads the primary key of each row from ws1 and finds the corresponding row with the same primary key in ws2 then all the other column attributes are matched between the two worksheets and reported accordingly.

The code is :

```
     Sub DataComparator(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
     Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Integer, ws2col As Integer
     Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Integer, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
     Dim difference As Long, reportrow As Long, reportcol As Long, flag As Boolean
     Dim row As Long, col As Long, pki As Long, pk As String, counter As Long
     Dim PctDone As Single, cell1 As String, cell2 As String, bfailed As Boolean

     TestDataComparator.FrameProgress.Visible = True
     TestDataComparator.LabelProgress.Visible = True

     'UserForm1.Visible = True
     'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     DoEvents

         With ws1.UsedRange
            ws1row = .Rows.Count
            ws1col = .Columns.Count
         End With

         With ws2.UsedRange
            ws2row = .Rows.Count
            ws2col = .Columns.Count
        End With
        maxrow = ws1row
        maxcol = ws1col

       pk = UCase(TestDataComparator.TextBox1.Value)

       For col = 1 To maxcol
           If pk = UCase(ws1.Cells(1, col).Formula) Then
               pki = col
           End If
       Next col

       If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
       If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

       difference = 0
       reportrow = 0
       For row = 2 To maxrow
           keyval = ws1.Cells(row, 1).Formula
           flag = False
           bfailed = False
           'reportcol = 1

           For col = 2 To maxcol
               'If col = pki Then
               'Exit For
               'End If
               counter = counter + 1
               cell1 = ""
               cell2 = ""
               cell1 = ws1.Cells(row, col).Formula
           On Error Resume Next
           'Set Rng = Range("A2:" & Cells(ws2row, "A").Address)
           cell2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(keyval,  ws2.UsedRange, col, False)
           If Err.Number <> 0 Then bfailed = True
           On Error GoTo 0
           If bfailed = True Then
               Exit For
           End If
           If cell1 <> cell2 Then
              flag = True
              'difference = difference + 1
              diffcolname = ws1.Cells(1, col)
              ws1.Cells(row, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
              ws1.Cells(1, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
              ws1.Cells(row, col).Font.Bold = True
              ws1.Cells(1, pki).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
              ws1.Cells(row, pki).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
              ws1.Cells(row, pki).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
              ws1.Cells(row, pki).Font.Bold = True
       End If

    Next col
    If flag = True Then
          reportrow = reportrow + 1
    End If
    PctDone = counter / (maxrow * maxcol)
    TestDataComparator.FrameProgress.Caption = "Progress..." &  Format(PctDone, "0%")
    TestDataComparator.LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * (TestDataComparator.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
    DoEvents
  Next row

  TestDataComparator.Totalcount.Value = row - 2
  TestDataComparator.mismatchCount.Value = reportrow
  TestDataComparator.mismatchCount.Font = Bold

  difference = 0
  For col = 1 To maxcol
          If ws1.Cells(1, col).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
              difference = difference + 1
              TestDataComparator.AttributeNameList.AddItem (ws1.Cells(1, col))
          End If
  Next col

  TestDataComparator.FrameProgress.Visible = False
  TestDataComparator.LabelProgress.Visible = False
  'TestDataComparator.PleaseWait.Visible = False
   MsgBox difference & " columns contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets"

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  End Sub
```

I want the vlookup function to search for the match only in the entire column of WS2 which has the primary key (index pki) rather than ws2.UsedRange. Please provide suggestions. Is there any option which will perform better than vlookup? The use of ws2.UsedRange is making it difficult to search in large datasets that is why I want to reduce search space. My dataset has above 40K rows and 155 columns in excel. Also suggest me a formula for calculating the progress in the progress bar if you think it is not appropriate.

**Sample data from OP's comment:**

```
Name    Height  Weight
Jane    5'6''   78
Mike    5'4''   89
Monica  5'2''   56
```

Comment: What is the nature of the `.UsedRange`? Is it one large contiguous block with no fully blank rows or columns that would create 'islands' of data? I see you start some things ar row 2. Does this mean that the first row has column header labels?

Comment: The .UsedRange is one contiguous block of the excel workbook which has  rows and cols filled with data (used space of workbook) .  The first row has column header labels. A sample data is as follows:                Row 1: Name Height Weight
Row 2: Jane        5'6''         78
Row 3: Mike        5'4''         89
Row 4: Monica    5'2''         56

Comment: `keyval = ws1.Cells(rw, 1).Formula` is deceptive. It seems that you are actually looking for `.Value` or `.Value2` and not a `.Formula` per se although `.Formula` will return a static value if the cell does not contain an actual formula.

Answer (score 2):

I think using a Dictionary (aka Hashtable in other languages) can make it faster. You will need to reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library.

You need to read ws2 key values with their row numbers into the Dictionary in one loop before you start going through ws1 row by row. Then in your loop you just look up the value in your dictionary to get its row number on ws2. Something like this:

```
Dim ws2keys As Dictionary
Set ws2keys = New Dictionary
' assuming you have a header row
For row = 2 To ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    keyValue = ws1.Cells(row, 1).Value
    If keyValue <> "" Then ws2keys.Add(keyValue, row)
Next
' your dictionary is ready
```

Then in your loop, instead of using VLookup when going row by row on ws1:

```
ws2RowIndex = ws2keys.Item(ws1KeyValueYouAreLookingFor)
```

(The code might not be perfect, I do not have anything Microsoft related on this machine to check the syntax, sorry.)

Comment: Might also find this helpful if you don't have Dictionaries activated in excel: http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/vba_dictionary.html
The third paragraph down tells you how to activate the .dll you need for it to work

Answer (score 0):

I've reduced your `VLOOKUP` for every column to a single `MATCH` to verify that it exists and one `MATCH` to set the `WS2` row where the match occurs. Everything else is done with direct addressing.

```
Sub DataComparator(ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet)
    Dim ws1row As Long, ws2row As Long, ws1col As Long, ws2col As Long
    Dim maxrow As Long, maxcol As Long, colval1 As String, colval2 As String
    Dim difference As Long, reportrow As Long, reportcol As Long, flag As Boolean
    Dim rw As Long, cl As Long, pki As Long, pk As String, counter As Long
    Dim cell1 As String, cell2 As String, bfailed As Boolean
    Dim iPCT As Long, ws2rw As Long, rWS1cr As Range, rWS2cr As Range, keyval As Variant, app As Application

    Set app = Application
    'UserForm1.Visible = True
    app.ScreenUpdating = False
    'DoEvents

    With ws1.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        Set rWS1cr = .Cells
        ws1row = .Rows.Count
        ws1col = .Columns.Count
    End With

    With ws2.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        Set rWS2cr = .Cells
        ws2row = .Rows.Count
        ws2col = .Columns.Count
    End With
    maxrow = ws1row
    maxcol = ws1col

    'pk = UCase(TestDataComparator.TextBox1.Value)
    For cl = 1 To maxcol
        If pk = UCase(rWS1cr.Cells(1, cl).Value) Then
            pki = cl
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cl

    If maxrow < ws2row Then maxrow = ws2row
    If maxcol < ws2col Then maxcol = ws2col

    difference = 0
    reportrow = 0
    With rWS1cr
        For rw = 2 To maxrow
            keyval = ws1.Cells(rw, 1).Value
            If Not IsError(app.Match(keyval, rWS2cr.Columns(1), 0)) Then
                ws2rw = app.Match(keyval, rWS2cr.Columns(1), 0)
                flag = False

                For cl = 2 To maxcol
                    counter = counter + 1
                    cell1 = vbNullString
                    cell2 = vbNullString
                    cell1 = .Cells(rw, cl).Value
                    cell2 = rWS2cr.Cells(ws2rw, cl).Value

                    If cell1 <> cell2 Then
                         flag = True
                         'diffcolname = .Cells(1, cl)
                         .Cells(rw, cl).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                         .Cells(1, cl).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                         .Cells(rw, cl).Font.Bold = True
                         .Cells(1, pki).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                         .Cells(rw, pki).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                         .Cells(rw, pki).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                         .Cells(rw, pki).Font.Bold = True
                    End If

                Next cl
                reportrow = reportrow - CLng(flag)
                If iPCT <> CLng((rw / maxrow) * 100) Then
                    iPCT = CLng((rw / maxrow) * 100)
                    app.StatusBar = "Progress - " & Format(iPCT, "0\%")
                End If
            End If
        Next rw
        For cl = 1 To maxcol
            If .Cells(1, cl).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                difference = difference + 1
                'TestDataComparator.AttributeNameList.AddItem (ws1.Cells(1, col))
            End If
        Next cl
        MsgBox difference & " columns contain different data! ", vbInformation, "Comparing Two Worksheets"
    End With

    difference = 0


    app.ScreenUpdating = True
    app.StatusBar = vbNullString

    Set app = Nothing
End Sub
```

I prefer `.CurrentRegion` to `.UsedRange` as I find it more reliable. This code was not tested but it does compile and I had to comment out a number of external references to get that to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I wanted. I made some changes in your code and it is working fine.